# Create slide with render dynamically in Rmarkdown shiny presentation

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I want to produce slide dynamically in my Rmarkdown presentation with shiny

Here below the code works.
But as soon as **I uncomment the for loop** it doesn't.

````
---
title: "dynamic_plots"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
number_of_bins_selected <- c(20,30)

i <- 1 # If for loop commented
#for (i in 1:length(number_of_bins_selected)) {

  cat("## New slide  \n")

  input1_id <- paste(i, "nbreaks", sep = "_")
  input2_id <- paste(i, "bw_adjust", sep = "_")

  inputPanel(
    selectInput(input1_id, label = "Number of bins:",
                choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = number_of_bins_selected[i]),

    sliderInput(input2_id, label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
  )

  renderPlot({
    hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input[[input1_id]]),
         xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

    dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input[[input2_id]])
    lines(dens, col = "blue")
  }) 
  cat("  \n\n") # End the slide
#}

```
````

Isn't it possible to create slides on a for loop ?

Comment: Your for loop does not loop. Try `i in 1:length(number_of_bins_selected)` or just `i in number_of_bins_selected`. If you try the latter you have to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Yes my for loop was wrong. I updated the question because presentation still stay empty.